# Eclipse GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I saw there are more topics about this problem, but I don't found any solution for my case.

I tried :

```
-> Clean Project / Restart Eclipse (and Mac too)
-> Change XMS size in eclipse.ini
-> Delete JAR and add again
```

I saw this "crash" doesn't appear if I uncheck "android privates libraries" in my project's properties..... Why ? What am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the xms, that does not help with GC overhead limits, as it sets up the starting heap size, not the heap size.

As a summary, the following common options are used to manage the JVMs memory usage:

- -Xms1G sets the starting heap size, while -Xmx1G sets the maximum heap size.
- -XX:MaxPermSize=320M sets the size of area where the class files are stored. Only used until Java 7, not required in Java 8 (and possibly in some JVM implementations in general). In most cases, its default value is correct; if not, a different error message is shown that the PermGen space was exhausted.

Related your original issue, I'd look at the maximum heap size setting (you can look at the settings your Eclipse started in Help/Installation details..., and select the configuration page; see screenshot below). If that is in the 512M-1G ballpark, I'd try to increase it, if it's over 2GB, there is something that leaks memory excessively.

[image: Memory settings]

Furthermore, as you are using Mac, you should look at the Info.plist file inside of your installation, as it might have additional related settings as well.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what I have to do :/ "you can look at the settings your Eclipse started in Help/Installation details..., and select the configuration page)" where is it ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a corresponding screenshot; there you can see the dialog that opens after selecting Help/Installation details... I hope, this way its easier to understand.